# Checking for IS NULL not working as expected

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a written a `SP` which gives me records based on the conditions I have selected from front end.

The issue is that whenever I select status as `Success` it works fine and gives me result for success. But when I select `Pending` which is `IS NULL` it does not works as required.

Below is my SP

```
PROCEDURE GET_ALL_STATE_FOR_EXCEL
  (
    P_STATUS NVARCHAR2,
    TBLDATA_STATE_ALL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
 AS BEGIN
      OPEN TBLDATA_STATE_ALL FOR 
        Select * from ubr_structure_details where NE_STATUS = P_STATUS;

      NULL;
 END GET_ALL_STATE_FOR_EXCEL;
```

**UPDATE**

When I select ALL and `Pending` it works properly.

But when I select some state name and status as pending it doesn't work properly. For that my query is below

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL
(
    P_STATE NVARCHAR2,
    P_STATUS NVARCHAR2,
    TBL_STATE_REP OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
    BEGIN
      OPEN TBL_STATE_REP FOR 
           select * from ubr_structure_details where (state = P_STATE) and (NE_STATUS = p_status OR NE_STATUS = 'IS NULL');           
        NULL;
END  GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL;
```

Comment: I'm really far from being a PL/SQL guru but... What purpose does having a single `NULL` as statement try to accomplish?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: it will give me the status for NULL values

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález none. it's probably a leftover from a previous empty block. vvvv, are you trying to say that P_STATUS is NULL, and that the query therefore does not work as intended? If so, indeed NULL has a special behavior when used with the equal sign so I encourage you to read on

Comment: @Sebas: yes I want to check for P_status =  null, but it doesnt work that way. so I need to use IS NULL for checking it

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Updated the question

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sir , did you got it. do let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

You need to be explicit about the `NULL` value:

```
select * 
from ubr_structure_details
where (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS) or
      (NE_STATUS is null and P_STATUS is null);
```

I do not recommend using `NULL` as a "valid" value.  "Pending" seems like a valid status; it should be stored as a valid status value.

Some databases support `NULL`-safe comparisons (such as the ANSI standard `is not distinct from`.  However, Oracle does not yet support this functionality.

EDIT:

Passing `p_status` as the string `is null` seems like a really bad idea.  You really should fix the statuses.  But you can include this in the logic:

```
select * 
from ubr_structure_details
where (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS) or
      (NE_STATUS is null and P_STATUS = 'IS NULL');
```

Comment: Flash Gordon, the ubiquitous! :D

Comment: its not working for me, From front end I am passing pending as `IS NULL`

Comment: @vvvv as a string??

Comment: @Sebas: yes, can u suggest any other way for this

Comment: Yeah well that clarifies things. Check the update on my post. But seriously you need to reconsider your architecture.  The more you'll wait to refactor the more problems will arise

Comment: can u suggest some other way for doing this. Tried your latest code too. getting the same error

Comment: sir, your second query worked for me. But can u suggest some better way to handle this. As I know this is not the accurate way of doing this

Comment: sir, for second condition like below `select * from ubr_structure_details where (state = P_STATE) and (NE_STATUS = p_status OR NE_STATUS = 'IS NULL');`  the pending status is getting failed. other than `is null` it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Gordon's, you could try that too:

```
SELECT * FROM ubr_structure_details 
WHERE COALESCE(NE_STATUS, 'IS NULL') = COALESCE(P_STATUS, n'IS NULL');
```

Pretty sure that'd break any index on `NE_STATUS` tho. If so, and supposing you can't fix your architecture such as recommended by Gordon, then you could add a function based index to match the new filters.

Comment: what will it do ?

Comment: getting error as `Error(192,105): PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch`

Comment: Okay, looks like we need a bit of convertion, try the updated  code

Comment: still getting the same error `Error(192,71): PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch`

Comment: what's the data type of NE_STATUS?

Comment: its `VARCHAR2(100)`

Comment: okay so see update please. If you keep having character set errors you´ll have to fix that on your own I think it requires some investigations

Comment: is this the best way to implement this ? or can u suggest some another best way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141358/discussion-between-vvvv-and-sebas).